# Why didn't the Ministry of Magic investigate the killing of Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, severus-snape, ministry-of-magic

Dumbledore planned his death by Snape killing him so that the Dark Lord will trust the Potions Master. In the *Half-Blood Prince*, The Ministry of Magic accepts that Voldemort is back. Hence, the former Minister of Magic, Cornelius Fudge was forced to resign his position and leaves the Ministry in disgrace. He was replaced by Rufus Scrimgeour. After the battle of the Astronomy tower, the two  Ministry of Magic officials visit Dumbledore's funeral.

Now, the Ministry of Magic didn't bother to investigate the Death of the Headmaster. Particularly, where Rufus Scrimgeour is now in charge. Dumbledore even said that the new Minister is a *"Man of action, doesn't underestimate Lord Voldemort".* With that said, we could expect that the Minister would investigate Dumbledore's death. Of course, the Ministry doesn't know that Dumbledore planned to have Snape kill him. But looking at what Snape did, it causes shock among wizards and people in Hogwarts. Even the whole Order of the Phoenix and Hogwarts community thinks of him as a traitor. Therefore, the Ministry has a good reason to investigate the murder of Albus Dumbledore. They could've questioned Harry Potter since he was the only one who was there and is on the same side as Dumbledore. If they ask Harry, then the Minister could try to arrest Snape.

*Take note: I'm referring to the Ministry of Magic prior to its control by Lord Voldemort. So therefore, I'm pertaining between the events of Half Blood Prince and Deathly Hallows.*

Comment: There's no indication that they *don't* know what happened or who killed Dumbledore. Snape flees immediately afterwards, and has the support of Voldemort and several other powerful wizards - who are actively working to infiltrate the Ministry - to protect him.

Comment: Spoiler in title.

Comment: @guest Lol, The book already came out 15 years ago.While the movie came out 11 years ago. So the spoiler won't be that intense anymore as it's already old.

Answer (score 5):

**What is there to investigate?**

There are multiple witnesses to Death Eaters attacking Hogwarts the night Dumbledore died, and Harry Potter himself states that Snape killed Dumbledore.

As a known Death Eater, Snape has little next to nothing *benefit of the doubt*.

The Ministry may very well have closed the matter, because all letters are spelling it as a Voldemort attack on his greatest enemy, nothing particularly weird.

Comment: Though note that later Harry thinks the following: *Nobody but those who had been on top of the tower when Dumbledore died knew who had really killed him and, as Rita Skeeter had already told the Wizarding world, Harry had been seen running from the place moments after Dumbledore had fallen.*

Comment: @Alex One thing is what a gossip jornalist may write in a newspaper to sell, and an entirely different thing is what the Ministry knows. And evidently the Ministry **knows** that Death Eaters were in Hogwarts that night (because as I said, witnesses, some of them were even Aurors, maybe?).

Comment: Even blatantly obvious murders are subjected to an inquest or postmortem. The wizarding world seems to be extremely backwards when it comes to justice, however.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Indeed. Let's remember that Sirius didn't even got a trial because there were witnesses stating that he murdered an entire street of muggles (plus Pettigrew). I highly doubt there was an investigation either, because honestly a Prior Incanto with Sirius' wand would've sufficed to clarify that he never killed anyone.

Comment: @marcellothearcane In addition, I suppose that if a bunch of wizards, a few of which are Aurors, state that Death Eaters were attacking in Hogwarts that night, I guess it's just "1+1" to determine who killed Dumbledore, right? No need of an extensive investigation.

Comment: Apparently not, since there was enough doubt that they could accuse Harry in the seventh book.

Comment: @marcellothearcane In the seventh book, Harry was accused only because the Ministry was under Voldemort's control and they wanted to discredit him.

Comment: @Roberto if that's the case why didn't they arrest Snape?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar Why didn't they arrest Voldemort? Yeah. They couldn't find him, nor Snape. And when the Ministry is under Voldemort control, Snape is just free of all charges.

Comment: Take note when Dumbledore died. voldemort wasn't control of the ministry yet. It was still Rufus Scrimgeour.

Comment: @TheWitchKingOfAngmar I know. What I'm saying is that the Ministry couldn't find Snape to arrest him, and when Voldemort seized control of the Ministry, Snape was free of charges.

Comment: Then why couldn't they find  Snape?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar In case you haven't noticed, Snape is a really skilled mage and was under the protection of the most powerful wizard in all Britain (Voldemort). Plus, the Ministry is... well... pretty much useless. This question is just like "Why couldn't they find Voldemort?"

Comment: Even though, Scrimgeour is under control the ministry is useless?

Answer (score 4):

The Ministry was allocating its resources to other activities. From Chapter Seven of *Deathly Hallows*:

> "Interesting theory." said Harry. "Has anyone tried to sticking a sword in Voldemort? Maybe the Ministry should put some people onto that, instead of wasting their time stripping down Deluminators or covering up breakouts from Azkaban. So is this what you've been doing, Minister, shut up in your office, trying to break open a snitch? People are dying – I was nearly one of them – Voldemort chased me across three counties, he killed Mad-Eye Moody, but there's been no word about any of that from the Ministry, has there? And you still expect us to cooperate with you!"

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your quote? It's a little unclear how your quote supports your original claim.